# Placing two divs side-by-side underneath another larger, centered div?

Tags: css, html

I'm wanting to place two divs (bboxl & bboxr) underneath a centered div (box1). Divs bboxl and bboxr are, including the borders, half the size of bbox1.

There should also be a 10px horizontal buffer (padding?) between box1 and bboxl/bboxr as well as a 10px vertical buffer between bboxl and bboxr.

This is the CSS for the divs:

```
#box1 {
margin: 10px auto;
padding: 10px 0px 10px 0;
height: 298px;
width: 918px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}

#bboxl, #bboxr {
padding: 0px 5px 0 5px;
height: 298px;
width: 398px;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
```

[However, I end up with this.](http://jsfiddle.net/uedu8/3/)

What could I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you currently have your other boxes inside `box1` close the `<div>` tag for `box 1` before you add the other two

add: `</div>` about `<div id="wrap">` then set bboxl & bboxr to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

```
#box1 {
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0;
    height: 298px;
    width: 918px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#box1 h1 {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#bboxl, #bboxr {
    height: 298px;
    width: 398px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    float: left;
}

#bboxl {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** - The top div
  In the code provided in your example, the top div was never closed so the bottom two boxes were coded into the top box (the top div). Possibly just a typo when transferring it online.

**Second** - The bottom divs
  You need to add `display: inline-block` in order to have the boxes display next to each other. If you add the CSS and resize the boxes to fit into JSFiddle, they'll fit beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display:inline-block` to your `bboxl,bboxr`. This will place them side by side!

And if you want a gap of 10px between the boxes, use `margin: 0 5px` instead of padding.